# How can I enter a sequence of numbers with an EOS in a vector without the EOS in it?

Tags: c++, vector, sequence

I enter a squencie of doubles in a vector but the last number is an EOS. How i dont enter that last number which stop the sequence?.

```
double vec[MAX];
int i = 0;
    while(vec[i-1] !=  EOS){
        cin >> vec[i];
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: You want to 1. Read input, 2. Check if it's valid, and 3. insert if so, break otherwise. That sounds like a do {} while(); loop would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [program](https://onlinegdb.com/30M1MdOoa) to add the number from the sequence just read into the `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
   std::vector<double> vec; //or you can create the vector of a particular size using std::vector<double> vec(size);
   
   double EOS = 65; //lets say this is the EOS
   std::string sequence; //or you can use std::string sequence = "12 43 76 87 65";
   std::getline(std::cin, sequence);//read the sequence of numbers
   
   std::istringstream ss(sequence);
   double temp;
   while((ss >> temp) && (temp!=EOS))
   {
       vec.push_back(temp);
   }
   
   std::cout<<"elements of the above vector are: "<<std::endl;
   //lets print out the elements of the vector 
   for(const double &elem: vec)
   {
       std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

The [output](https://onlinegdb.com/30M1MdOoa) of the above program is(for a given input shown below):

```
12 43 78 98 65
elements of the above vector are: 
12
43
78
98
```